# MySQLi prepare update not updating the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

As the title states, my MySQLi prepared update is not actually updating the database.  I have checked the MySQL logs - no errors.  Here is the code in question:

```
public function update_tweet($tweet)
{
    $prepared_update = $this->connection->prepare("UPDATE Tweets 
                     SET `text` = ?, `algo_score` = ?, `has_algo_score` = ?, `baseline_score` = ?, `has_baseline_score` = ?, `is_sanitized` = ?
                     WHERE `twitter_id` = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepared_update, "sssssss", $tweet['text'], $tweet['algo_score'], $tweet['has_algo_score'], $tweet['baseline_score'], $tweet['has_baseline_score'], $tweet['is_sanitized'], $tweet['tweet_id']);
    mysqli_execute($prepared_update) or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));
    $prepared_update->close();
}
```

And an example of the tweet array being passed in:

```
Array ( [id] => 2 
        [twitter_id] => 595463376026734592 
        [text] => History has a way of repeating itself 
        [algo_score] => 0 
        [has_algo_score] => 1 
        [baseline_score] => 0 
        [has_baseline_score] => 1 
        [is_sanitized] => 1 
)
```

And the table schema:

[image]

No PHP errors or MySQL errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the mySQL query logs to see if anything is actually coming through? Mine is at `/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.log`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - it was just a simple misspelling.  Noob status :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition:

```
WHERE `twitter_id` = ?
```

The variable that you're binding is:

```
$tweet['tweet_id']
```

While the array you're getting is:

```
Array ( [id] => 2 
        [twitter_id] => 595463376026734592
```

So you're using the wrong index and since the index `tweet_id` is undefined (it's just a notice, you're receiving no errors or warnings) your `WHERE` condition would never return true, therefore - no action is being taken.

Comment: My god that's embarassing...thank you.  Any way to report notices as well?  I have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` set on my output page.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens to everyone from time to time, so that's ok. `E_ALL` should show notices.